# Who is Manu of Manu Smriti?

Tags: manu-smriti, manu

The Manu of Manu Smriti is same as Manus of Manvantar or he is any rishi?
Also, which Manu he is if he is Manu of Manvantar?

Comment: He is swayambhuva Manu

Comment: @Archit Are you sure it's Svayambhuva and not Vaivasvata?

Comment: @Surya yes 100% sure. Not writing an answer because I have a slight confusion between who’s Virat and feeling lazy to write an answer. Anyway gave the question a +1 vote

Comment: @Archit no problem sir. This much is enough. I just wanted to know who the author of manu smriti is and you already answered that. Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As per Verse [1.59](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/manusmriti-with-the-commentary-of-medhatithi/d/doc145482.html) and [1.61](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/manusmriti-with-the-commentary-of-medhatithi/d/doc145486.html), the Manu of Manu Smriti is the first Manu named Svāyambhuva Manu of first (Svāyambhuva manvantra):

> [**Manu**:]
>
> This Bhṛgu will fully describe to you this (Law); this sage has learnt the whole of this in its entirety, **from me**.—(59)

> [Bhṛgu:]
>
> **स्वायम्भु**वस्यास्य मनोः षड्वंश्या मनवोऽपरे ।
>
> सृष्टवन्तः प्रजाः स्वाः स्वा महात्मानो महौजसः ॥ ६१ ॥
>
> There are Six other Manus, high-souled and mighty, who belong to the same race as **this Svāyambhuva Manu**, and have called into being, each his own offsprings.—(61)

Answer (score 0):

We are living in the time of Vaivaswatha Manu. I believe this Manu we are following. Every Manu writes his own rules depending upon the nature of the people of his time.

Comment: There are 14 Manus in total. Each Manu has his own set of rules for each manvantara ruled by him. Although the name Manu is common the present Vaivasvata manvantara began with the advent of the aforesaid Manu only. This is clear.